# Accord.NET: how to train Boost classifier

Tags: c#, machine-learning, accord.net, boosting

I'm trying to use Accord.NET library for objects classification, but I failed to find any suitable examples and documentation is not enough to understand the process. My current code is

```
Predictor = new Boost<DecisionStump>();
AdaBoost<DecisionStump> Algo = new AdaBoost<DecisionStump>(Predictor, new ModelConstructor<DecisionStump>((double[] weights) => new DecisionStump(10)));
Algo.Run(set.X, set.Y);
```

It's written so just to be "compilable", but I have no idea what is the essence of the **inputs** parameter of **DecisionStump** and the whole second **AdaBoost** parameter. Could somebody explain, how to create and train **Boost** classifier properly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the input data and output labels for training, which you mentioned as set.X and set.Y.
Typically it is by giving as parameters double[][] inputs and int[] outputs:

```
Algo.Run(inputs, outputs);
```